# configure the EHCache with mysql in Mule

Tags: mule, ehcache

In mule, I have wrapped MySQL DB connector inside a Cache scope and configured a custom cache strategy, which is EHCache.

So, whenever there is a repeated request to the cache scope, it should return the data which is stored in its cache. But it didn't worked that way. So, I have gone through this post
[How to configure the EHCache with CXF in Mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639270/how-to-configure-the-ehcache-with-cxf-in-mule/29657547#29657547)

As per the suggestions, I split my code into two and used VM and object-to-string transformer at request and response of the Cache scope

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="cacheManager" name="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"/>
    <spring:bean id="cache" name="cache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
        <spring:property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
        <spring:property name="cacheName" value="dbCache"/>
        <spring:property name="maxElementsInMemory" value="10000"/>
        <spring:property name="eternal" value="false"/>
        <spring:property name="timeToIdle" value="120"/>
        <spring:property name="timeToLive" value="120"/>
        <spring:property name="overflowToDisk" value="true"/>
        <spring:property name="maxElementsOnDisk" value="10000000"/>
        <spring:property name="diskPersistent" value="false"/>
        <spring:property name="diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds" value="120"/>
        <spring:property name="memoryStoreEvictionPolicy" value="LRU"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>

<ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy">
    <custom-object-store class="com.lineage.cache.EhcacheObjectStore">
        <spring:property name="cache" ref="cache"/>
    </custom-object-store>
</ee:object-store-caching-strategy>

  <flow name="highjumpdummyFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <ee:cache doc:name="Cache" cachingStrategy-ref="Caching_Strategy">
        <logger message="#['Into the Cache Block']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="DBCache" connector-ref="VM" doc:name="VM">
            <vm:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
        </vm:outbound-endpoint>
       </ee:cache>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>

  <flow name="highjump_dummyFlow1">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="DBCache" connector-ref="VM" doc:name="VM">
        <vm:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </vm:inbound-endpoint>
    <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[select * from HIGHJUMP_INVOICE_CHARGE_STAGING;]]></db:dynamic-query>
    </db:select>
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Map_To_XML" doc:name="Map To XML"/>
    <byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
</flow>
```

But now, i got a new problem. Inside my second flow at the DB connector the mule flow is failing with 
org.mule.api.MessagingException: Could not bind connection to current transaction: org.mule.transport.vm.VMTransaction@90b65fe0-e408-11e4-ae24-d43d7e1497b8[status=STATUS_ACTIVE, key=null, resource=null] (org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.ConnectionBindingException). Message payload is of type: String

Console Message:
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Can only bind "QueueManager/QueueSession" type resources
    at org.mule.transport.vm.VMTransaction.bindResource(VMTransaction.java:41)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.getConnectionFromTransaction(TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.java:110)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.createConnection(TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.java:72)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the **transaction** part in **VM** which is causing the issue, and follow the same as given here :-
http://blogs.mulesoft.org/guest-post-exposing-cxf-webservice-mule-cache/
and also put
 `<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>`  before Cache block to make the payload cacheble

And to be honest, you can directly place the **Database** component directly under **Cache scope** instead of dividing the flow into 2. It will work ..

Comment: Thanks Anirban, really appreciate it. yes, i tried without VM in my flow. But didn't used object to string transformer earlier. It worked now. I have another question, why we need VM in cache particularly for a Webservice call?

Comment: Earlier I tried to implement web services within Cache scope .. But it was not able to cache and was failing for strange reason .. Then I divided the flow into 2 using VM and found implementing VM was much easier and cachable for web services :) ..